# jsfiddle - Tutorial demo not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

I'm reading the [jsfiddle tutorial](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/tutorial.html) and copied the demo to jsfiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/cdt86915998/ps6shugt/. Running this demo in chrome and console gives `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`.

I suppose this error is caused by javascript configuration, but I already have jQuery(edge) configured.

This is my code:

```
$('test').addEvent('click', (function() {
    $('test').set('html', 'Goodbye World!')
    $('test').fade('out');
}));
```

Comment: Giving your jsFiddle a quick look, you haven't imported jQuery to it and also your first selector is wrong.

Comment: it's not working because jquery library is not included in html code

Comment: You didn't follow the tutorial you linked to, which told you to select the MooTools library, not jQuery. If you follow the instructions it works: https://jsfiddle.net/ps6shugt/5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select MooTools not jQuery as your Javascript Frameworks and Extensions.

From your tutorial:

> We are using MooTools (jsFiddle’s default library) to do a number of
>   things

Answer (score 0):

please change `addEvent` to `on` function. You clearly don't have the proper knowledge about jQuery functions. Please refer the jquery doc properly

```
$('#test').on('click', (function() {
   $('#test').html('Goodbye World!')
   $('#test').fadeOut();
}));
```

Comment: The tutorial the OP was following wasn't a jQuery one, it uses MooTools.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed from the question you were using jQuery - if so, your syntax is wrong. 
Other answers have solved your issue using mootools, so you're better off following their advice if that's the library you're trying to use.

**With jQuery**
To select the `div` by id you need to add a `#` to its selector.
Also, some of your jQuery methods were incorrect. Try using this code below:

```
$('#test').on('click', function() {
    $('#test').html('Goodbye World!')
    $('#test').fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: So the documentation is WRONG! Thanks.

Comment: No the syntax is not wrong, please look at my answer, @callodacity has changed it to use jQuery instead of what is given in tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to persist in using jQuery, try updating the javascript section as follows:

```
$('#test').on('click', (function() {
    $('#test').html('Goodbye World!');
    $('#test').fadeOut(1000);
}));
```

This corrects the syntax for selecting by id using `#id`.  The error you are seeing is because .set and .fade are not jquery functions.

Comment: The tutorial the OP was following wasn't jQuery.

Comment: Good point, in that case most of the attempts at answering are wrong.  The OP does think they are using jQuery too though.

Answer (score -2):

If you look at the Tutorial it requires 'Mootools' and not 'jquery' which is what you have tried to insert. jQuery doesn't have addEvent. Try with mootools and it will work straight away

Comment: You *did* ask about this on Meta, so I will refer you to [Your answer is in another castle!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/175248) to potentially explain why particular answer isn't looked on so favorably.

Comment: That is incorrect, please look at the selected answer and my downvoted answer and they both are same. What is frustrating is some one just did this as a "to annoy downvote" I think some policies should be re visited as I spent time on finding what the issue was and only to be downvoted just because some have lot of points at their disposal